# How a pointer be deallocated after it's initialized inside a function or an if-else statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I never thought of this but I'm a bit curious but what if I initialize a pointer inside an if-else statement like this?

```
if (true)
{
    int *p=(int*)malloc (sizeof (int));
}   // Will p be freed here?
// Can't free (p) here since it is not in this scope
```

I think the code tells pretty much everything about my question... I actually have a thought like this, it is necessary to `free(p)` at the end of `if` statement, but what if it's inside a loop?

```
for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
{
    int *p=(int*)malloc (sizeof (int));
    // Some code here
    free (p);   // Will p deallocated 5 times or just once?
}
```

Comment: First one is a memory leak. Second one allocates memory 5 times and frees it 5 times, so this one is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 1st example, **no** it won't. You just introduced a *memory leak*, yikes!

`p` is a variable (a pointer) with scope inside the body of the if statement.

So when we reach the end of that body, `p` will go out of scope, and you won't have any pointer available to that memory you just dynamically allocated at the start of the if statement's body.

As a result, you cannot free that memory (since you have no pointer to pass to the free method).

To fix this code, you should do this:

```
if (true)
{
  int *p = malloc (sizeof (int));
  free(p);
}
```

---

In your 2nd example, `p` will be allocated **one time per loop** execution, which is the *correct behavior*.

Think in it like this:

1. 1st loop: We dynamically allocate memory and store a pointer to it in `p`. De-allocate the memory pointed by `p`.
2. 2nd loop: We dynamically allocate memory and store a pointer to it in `p`. De-allocate the memory pointed by `p`.
3. 3rd loop: We dynamically allocate memory and store a pointer to it in `p`. De-allocate the memory pointed by `p`.
4. 4th loop: We dynamically allocate memory and store a pointer to it in `p`. De-allocate the memory pointed by `p`.
5. 5th loop: We dynamically allocate memory and store a pointer to it in `p`. De-allocate the memory pointed by `p`.

---

PS: Unrelated to what you are asking, but read this: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No.

Comment: `p` born inside the `if` statement and will be gone after the `if` statement is executed but the allocated memory still there, and that may results in a memory leak, correct?

Comment: The description: _'Dynamically allocate memory, pointed by `p`'_ is a bit misleading. We do not allocate a memory _pointed by `p`_ here, because `p` has no meaningful value at the moment of allocation. What happens in the code would better be described as 'we dynamically allocate memory and store a pointer to it in `p`'.

Comment: @LastSecond959 exactly!

Comment: @CiaPan I'd agree, answer rephrased, tnx!